# How can control settings of basefilter in dspack by delphi

Tags: delphi, settings, dspack, ffdshow

I add ffdshow in basefilter of dspack,
How do I change the settings like brightness, etc. at runtime in Delphi 7

Comment: Check the `ColorControl` object property of the `TDSVideoWindowEx2` class.

Comment: I want to change value of ffdshow settings only